# lua - how to convert a UTC time to 12 hr EST time

Tags: lua

**Background**

I get the following date back from the system:

```
>print(os.date("%d.%m.%y.%c")) 
30.11.16.Wed Nov 30 15:39:11 2016
```

I am trying to figure out how to convert the time so I get back 10:39:11 instead of 15:39:11

So far as a test, I've tried this:

```
> print(os.date("%I"))
03
```

and

```
> print(os.date("%d.%m.%y %I"))     
30.11.16 03
>
```

**Question**

I guess I don't understand why I'm getting back "03".

**What I've Tried**

I tried to set the locale information using

os.setlocale('en')

and then retried the os.date command but it's still returning the 03. 
Can you tell me what the 03 represents, as well as how I can get back the current time for my time zone (Eastern) and in a 12 hr format?

Thanks.

Comment: `print(os.date("!%d.%m.%y.%c")) `

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff that still returns the time in 24 hr format

Comment: `os.date("%d.%m.%y %r")`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 03, because as it states in the [Corona docs](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/os/date.html):

> %I: Hour in 12-hour format (01 – 12)

I'd recommend you check what timezone you are getting using `%z`. Also read that piece of documentation, as all the information you need is there.